Driving stepper motor with higher voltage
I have a DC Motor + Stepper FeatherWing and I am trying to drive a ST2018S0604-C stepper motor. The motor is rated at 3.9V and the specification of the motor driver TB6612 on the FeatherWing board specifies 4.5V to 13.5V. Even though the voltage required for the motor is lower, will this still work? If not, is there something I could modify on the FeatherWing to make it work?
I tried using the Adafruit Motor Shield library but I did not manage to drive the stepper motor yet.

Stepper motors are usually driven at a higher that rated voltage as Jonathan notes. Another way of looking at the same situation is that a high voltage current limited feed approximates a current source with high effective resistance (impedance). Electrical time constant of drove is sqrt(L/R). Higher effective R decreases the effective time constant. || The driver needs to ensure that drive maximum parameters are not exceeded.

Stepper motors are generally driven with a phase current, not a voltage. The reason for this is that the inductance (and back-EMF) of the windings causes a larger voltage drop when the motor is spinning versus when it's standing still. As a result, while this motor might need 3.9V to hold its position, it will need more than that voltage to actually rotate an attached load.
The driver IC you've linked is unsuitable for controlling a stepper motor. It's made for plain (brushed) DC motors instead. If you attach a stepper nevertheless, it's likely going to damage it (by overheating the motor).
It's a bit strange that the website would advertise this board for controlling steppers when it's clearly not suited for that task.
If you want to try it anyway, you could power the board with 5V and put 2.2 Ohm resistors in series with each one of the motor's windings to lower the current to something that won't damage the motor. Note though that the resistors will get rather hot and you'll need to use at least 1 Watt types, ideally 2 Watt or higher.

I would power the FetherWing (Motor driver board) with 12V. What calculation would I use for the resistance required on both the coils? From the datasheet of the motor, Amps/phase is 0.6 and the resistance per phase is 6.5.

@dreamcoder You need to get rid of the excess voltage at the motor's rated current: R = (12V - 3.9V) / 0.6A = 13.5 Ohms. The power dissipation in each resistor is P = (12V - 3.9V) * 0.6A = 4.86W. If you were to build this, you could use 13 Ohm resistors rated for 10 Watts or higher for some safety margin. However, it would be much better if you just used a 5V power supply as the wasted power would be much lower.
